# Finding the value of $x$ when ${x\ln(x)=1}$ and ${x>0}$

Tags: logarithms

I have to find the solution to the equation above and show that it's the only solution with a value of somewhere between 1 and 2.

This is what I tried to do:

$$x\ln(x)=1$$
$$\ln(x)^x=1$$
$$e^1=x^x$$
$$e=x^x$$
and then I got lost. Any suggestions?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/355268/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1585888/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1290950/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2229463/42969 – all found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%20%5Cln(x)%20%3D%201%24)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving $e^\frac1x = x$ non-graphically?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1290950/solving-e-frac1x-x-non-graphically)

Comment: Yes, I think it does